# C# DataGrid Cell - Change row forecolor IF

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview, datagrid

I'm trying to change the forecolor of a specific row within a datagrid if a cell within that row contains the word "WARNING".

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in inclog.Rows)
        {
            if (inclog.SelectedCells[5].Value.ToString() == "WARNING")
            {

                inclog.SelectedRows[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            }
        }
```

I'm trying to change the code, add and remove bits but can't seem to be able to do it.

Comment: And that should only happen when the row is selected, or is that a mistake? I'm also a bit confused, because you use a foreach loop over all rows but you don't do anything with those rows.

Comment: Does the value of the cell have to be only "WARNING" or it can contain any other text? For example "WARNING A random error occured"? If it can, try trimming the string and using .Contains instead of ==

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a complete disconnect from what the text in the question says and what the code is doing. The posted code doesn’t really make sense and I will assume that what the text in the question says is what you want. Therefore, the solution below will do what is described in the text…

> *”I'm trying to change the forecolor of a specific row within a datagrid if a cell within that row contains the word "WARNING".”* …

What I can decipher, is that for “each” row in the grid, if one of the cells in that row contains the word “Warning”, then, you want to set the fore color (text) in that row to red. If this is correct, then the code below should work.

In the code, we loop through each of the “Rows” in the grid (ignoring the “new” row if present), then another loop through each of the “Cells” in that row. A check is made to see if that cells text contains the word “Warning.” If the cell DOES contain the word “Warning”, then the code sets that row’s fore color to red. Then “breaks” out of the “Cells” loop as we do not need to check further for the text “Warning.”

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in inclog.Rows) {
  if (!row.IsNewRow) {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
      if (cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString().Contains("Warning")) {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```